# 英語が残っている: 通報ボタン

Tags: バグ, 完了

[image]

> Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention

私が良いと思う翻訳は以下です。

> このコメントには問題がある、もしくはモデレータに通報する必要がある

Answer (score 1):

下記に改正しました。次回のビルドに適用します。

> このコメントには問題がある、もしくはモデレータに通報する必要がある

Comment: 上記に、私が良いと思った翻訳を追記しました。

Comment: @mattn ありがとう！助かりました！