# 「通報する」という言い方をやめませんか？

Tags: 討議, 翻訳

スタック・オーバーフローでは、各質問の下に[「通報」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)のためのリンクがあります。元々のStackOverflowでは ["flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) と書かれているものです。

[image: 「通報」が実際に書かれているスクリーンショット]

質問をクローズしたりするときに使われるので「通報」という言葉も間違ってはいないとは思うのですが、質問の重複やmigrationを提案するときにも使われるため、僕は「通報」だとニュアンスがあっていないのではないかと思っていました。
また、「通報」だと「悪いことを告発する」かのような意味にもとれ、コミュニティとして質問を良くしていくための取り組みを表す言葉として正確なのか疑問に思っていました。

そこで、この単語をより "flag" に近いニュアンスである「問題を報告する」ないし「報告」などの言葉で置き換えることを提案します。他に良い訳が思いついた方がいらっしゃればコメントお願いいたします。

なお「問題を報告する」という言い回しは、コメントへのフラグで使われています（[参考](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1414/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E6%AE%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-%E9%80%9A%E5%A0%B1%E3%83%9C%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3)）。

参考までに、ほかの外国語StackOverflowにおいてどのような言葉に訳されているのかを調べました。英語への翻訳はGoogle Translateを用いています。

- [スペイン語](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts): reporte …… 英語でreport
- [ポルトガル語](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts): sinalizar …… 英語でsignal
- [ロシア語](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts): тревоги …… 英語でalarm

---

#### 2017/01/26追記

> "flag"リンクだけ"報告"に変えればいいでしょうか？それとも通報という言い回しをサイト全体でなくした方がいいですか？ -- [コメントより](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2410/%E9%80%9A%E5%A0%B1%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E3%82%84%E3%82%81%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B#comment1852_2410)

"flag" リンクを変更するのであれば、[ヘルプセンターの「通報」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)なども変える必要があるように思います。つまり、"flag"自体の翻訳を「報告」に変えることを意図していました。その意味では「通報」という言い回しをサイト全体でなくそうとしています。

ただ、コメントのフラグの「このコメントには問題がある、もしくはモデレータに通報する必要がある」の「通報」まで「報告」に機械的に変更すると原文 "Flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention" の意図を損ねかねないので、細かい部分は翻訳者の方に任せ、何か気になるところがあれば都度メタ投稿すればよいのではないかと考えています。

#### 2017/01/27追記

[Myakuさんの回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2412/19110)により「評価の基準の理解が十分で‌​ないユーザが独自の評価で、どんどんタスク‌​を追加する」ことを防止するためにも「通報」のままで良いのではないか、という論点が指摘されました。

僕自身現段階で信用度が500に達していないため、このあたりについてはより信用度が高いユーザーさんの意見を伺いたいです。

#### 2017/03/18追記

Myakuさんの回答を承認しました。

しかし投稿としては現在差引+12も票が集まりました。もし他の意見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、随時回答として投じていた‌​だければと思います。

Comment: 良いかはわかりませんが、英語をそのまま訳して「フラグを立てる」

Comment: 例えば YouTube では"Flag"は「報告」で翻訳されてますね :)

Comment: Flagはmodelatorなどの注意を引くためのものですから、「(modelatorのために）目印をつける」とか「フラグを立てる」とかが良いのではないかと思います。

Comment: 「フラグを立てる」とか「目印をつける」とかママ言われても初めて見る人には何の機能か分からないかと思います。原文を尊重しすぎて使う人が何の機能か分からなくなっては元も子もないので、変更するのであれば”報告"に一票。また、スコアが伸びればクローズ票については「閉じる」が増えるので「通報」でも特に問題は感じていないです。

Comment: "flag"リンクだけ"報告"に変えればいいでしょうか？それとも通報という言い回しをサイト全体でなくした方がいいですか？

Comment: @unarist 追記しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: 変更してもよいと思いますが、コストに見合ったメリットがないような気がします。ただ、このサイトをよくしていくという意味ではニュアンスがあっていないというのは賛成です。変えるなら、報告でよいと思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"通報"についての機能は質問者側ではなく利用する側が使用する機能であることを前提としてお話します。
まず"通報"という言葉の定義が間違っているのか？どう言った意味を持つのか？という点ですが、
下記、一般的な認識と"デジタル大辞泉"から抜粋してきました。

> ［名］(スル)情報・ニュースなどを告げ知らせること。また、その知らせ。
>   特に、各種運営・組織などに事件などの解決を目的として事態を報告する事によく用いられる。

言葉の利用上は私としては間違ってはいないかと思います。
また、後述の「事件などを解決するために自体を報告する」ことによく使われることから
この"通報"という言葉にネガティブなイメージが強いかと思います。

では、このネガティブなイメージを誰が持つのか？と言ったところで
"通報"の機能を利用するのは実際に"通報"するユーザです。
質問者や回答者へは"通報"された旨ではなく「問題点」と「対処」が示されるかと思います。

この「"通報"がネガティブな意味を持つことで発生する問題は何か？」と考えたとき思いつくのが
「その機能に対し利用が消極的になる」ことだと私は考えます。
その場合は今回の議題では特に問題にならないかと考えました。

"通報"を行うことの多くが「自身のアカウントの権限では利用できない機能」を使用する際に
モデレータやレビュワーに問題点を伝えて代理で行うかと思います。
また、その際に"通報"にて利用できる機能は下記があるかと思います。

> - スパム
>     製品やサービスの広告のために使われていて、自分が関係者であることも隠しています。
> - 失礼又は暴言
>     乱暴な表現が含まれている、誰かを貶しているなど、礼節をわきまえた投稿とは言えません
> - クローズする必要があります
>     質問内容が不明、明らかに情報が不足している、範囲が広すぎる、主観的な回答しか集まらない、オフトピックなどの問題があり、編集で改善される見込みもありません。
> - 重複しています
>     この質問は以前投稿されたことがあり、回答がすでにあります。
> - 品質が低すぎる
>     この質問は、書式または内容に重大な問題があります。この質問はおそらく手直ししても十分改善されないため、削除しなければならないかもしれません。
> - モデレーターによる対応が必要です
>     その他の問題があり、モデレーターによる対応が必要です。問題を具体的に説明してください！

まず`クローズする必要があります`、`重複しています`については
[信用度 500点](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)より追加される`閉じる`機能から利用できるようになります。
クローズ票を使い切ったユーザや、権限の不足しているユーザは
そもそもの問題として**積極的にこの機能を使用するべきではない**と考えます。
(よほど重大な問題を抱えている質問や回答があるのであれば別)

他の機能については該当の質問や回答が削除されることが絡んできます。
その場合においても利用が消極的になることで問題が発生するとは思えません。

以上のことから、私としては"通報"という文言を変更することに余り大きな意味を感じません。

Comment: 十分に整理された回答をありがとうございます。権限の不足しているユーザーが「通報」機能を使用するべきではないという部分には何か根拠がありますか？　[ヘルプセンター](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)には「サイトで何か不快に感じることや、明らかにこのサイトに属しないと思うことがあった場合は、通報して注意喚起 *してください!* 」と書かれています。`クローズする必要があります` は「サイトに属しない」にあたらないのでしょうか。

Comment: 「使用するべきではない」ではなく「積極的に使用するべきではない」です。まだサイトに慣れておらず、評価の基準の理解が十分でないユーザが独自の評価で、どんどんタスクを追加することに問題を感じています。別に使用することが悪いと考えているわけではありません。(そのためのモデレータやレビュワー)

Comment: なるほど、納得しました。タスクが増えることについては、まだ私自身さほど信用度を得ているわけではないので、Myakuさんなど、より信用度の高いユーザーさんのご意見を伺いたいです。

Comment: まぁそうですね。消極的になっても問題がある質問などに関してはクローズ提案がなされますし、"通報”に関して、より慎重になるという点を見ると悪いことばかりではない気がしております。……これがもっと軽い機能に対しての翻訳提案であれば上記限りではないので「他の"報告"などの翻訳はどうなの？」といわれれば「また個別で…」となりますね。

Comment: 私の信用度が500を超えて1～2ヶ月経ち、何となくではありますが皆さんの気分が分かってきました。今でも「通報」の方が訳としては良いと思いますが、サイト内全てにおいて変更する労力とは釣り合わず、更にMyakuさんのおっしゃるようなこともあるので、私としてはこの回答を承認したいと思います。

Comment: しかし投稿としては差引+12も票が集まりました。もし他の意見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、随時回答として投じていただければと思います。